# how to change uiview position, height, using swift programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bottom_round_view1.frame = CGRectMake(256,741,15,15)

    }
```

It is not working.Kindly help me.

Comment: how is `bottom_round_view1` declared?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to declare bottom_round_view1 programmatically instead of using IBOutlet